# How to create a function that parses dates

Tags: function, t-sql

Hi I have the following code to create a function. Basically it parses dates and tells me the round number based on the date.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION VITAL_TARGET.roundfind(dates date)
 RETURNS varchar
 
AS

BEGIN


case 
    when dates between '2020-06-08' and '2020-11-14' then return 'Round 1'
    when dates between '2020-11-15' and '2021-02-17' then return 'Round 2'
    when dates between '2021-02-18' and '2021-04-28' then return 'Round 3'
    when dates between '2021-04-29' and '2021-07-16' then return 'Round 4'
    when dates between '2021-07-16' and '2021-10-03' then return 'Round 5'
    when dates between '2021-10-04' and '2021-11-30' then return 'Round 6'
    when dates between '2021-12-01' and '2022-02-01' then return 'Round 7'
    when dates between '2021-02-02' and '2022-03-28' then return 'Round 8'
    when dates >= '2022-03-29' then return 'Round 9'
end;
```

The following error is showing up:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure roundfind, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near 'dates'.
Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure roundfind, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 0]
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
```

Comment: `roundfind(dates date)`... `when dates`. You define `date` and as a column *not* a parameter. You also have no `RETURN` and you define the value you  don't `RETURN` value as a `varchar(1)`.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont get that. Can you please elaborate by how that would change the code above? thanks so much

Comment: I have the return in the case statement

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression**, not a statement, it returns a scalar value; you *cannot* define a `RETURN` in a `CASE` expression because it isn't a scalar value.

Comment: Can you please guide what approach to take then? This is the only way I know to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of with your function. Firstly you define your parameter as a column called `dates`, *not* a parameter (`@dates)`. Next you define you want the `FUNCTION` to return a `varchar(1)`, meaning it'll only ever return `NULL` or `'R'`.

Then you have you `CASE` expression which has statements for its scalar values; `return 'Round 1'` isn't a scalar value, it's s statement. As it's name suggests, a `CASE` expression is an **expression**, and as such it returns a scalar value, not a statement or boolean result.

In your `CASE` expression you also try to reference a column `dates` again, which doesn't exist as it doesn't have any content (there is no `FROM`).

You are also then missing an `END`, either for your `CASE` expression or your `BEGIN`:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION VITAL_TARGET.roundfind (@dates date)
RETURNS varchar(7)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN @dates BETWEEN '2020-06-08' AND '2020-11-14' THEN 'Round 1'
                WHEN @dates BETWEEN '2020-11-15' AND '2021-02-17' THEN 'Round 2'
                WHEN @dates BETWEEN '2021-02-18' AND '2021-04-28' THEN 'Round 3'
                WHEN @dates BETWEEN '2021-04-29' AND '2021-07-16' THEN 'Round 4'
                WHEN @dates BETWEEN '2021-07-16' AND '2021-10-03' THEN 'Round 5'
                WHEN @dates BETWEEN '2021-10-04' AND '2021-11-30' THEN 'Round 6'
                WHEN @dates BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2022-02-01' THEN 'Round 7'
                WHEN @dates BETWEEN '2021-02-02' AND '2022-03-28' THEN 'Round 8'
                WHEN @dates >= '2022-03-29' THEN 'Round 9'
           END;
END;
```

You can, however, make your `CASE` expression much more succinct with the following:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION VITAL_TARGET.roundfind (@dates date)
RETURNS varchar(7)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN @dates >= '2022-03-29' THEN 'Round 9'
                WHEN @dates >= '2021-02-02' THEN 'Round 8'
                WHEN @dates >= '2021-12-01' THEN 'Round 7'
                WHEN @dates >= '2021-10-04' THEN 'Round 6'
                WHEN @dates >= '2021-07-16' THEN 'Round 5'
                WHEN @dates >= '2021-04-29' THEN 'Round 4'
                WHEN @dates >= '2021-02-18' THEN 'Round 3'
                WHEN @dates >= '2020-11-15' THEN 'Round 2'
                WHEN @dates >= '2020-06-08' THEN 'Round 1'     
           END;
END;
```